# Python array dimensions

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, dimensions

I'm currently learning numpy and I find 'Array Dimensions' . Can anyone explain to me what are array dimensions ? How to find out the dimensions of an array ?
Thank you ,

Comment: array is used to store values of same type, In numpy you can check number of dimensions and items in an array is defined by its shape. 
you can check examples here: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print a tuple of the dimensions of an array like so:

```
print array.shape
```

Let's say it was (2,3). Your array might be: [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
So basically the first dimension is the number of elements in the outer part, then the second is the number of elements in an inner part, and so on...